# Installing windows after ubuntu is installed (need to create ntfs partition too)

Tags: boot, windows, system-installation

I prefer Ubuntu to work on, but for some applications for school, I need windows. I've done some research and have a few problems:

1. I only have one hard drive which is formatted as ext4, not ntfs. Many people say I have to use Gparted to create an ntfs partition to install windows on, the only problem is that I need to unmount my drive to do this, which isn't possible I think because I only have one. I thought about mounting my HDD as a slave on a windows laptop but I don't manage to partition it with windows partition manager, so I think I need some kind of tool. which one?
2. next problem I'll probably have is that I won't be able to boot ubuntu after installing windows because grub will be removed from my MBR. are there any good guides around here? I've used some kind of tool before, but it crashed my whole HDD so I had to fully format it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a live usb/cd disk of ubuntu. (you can use `startup disk creator` application in ubuntu).

Boot using that cd/usb. Now install gparted in live usb/cd. Issue following in a terminal

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

Now use `gparted` to create a ntfs volume. Since you are running from usb/cd the hard disk won't be mounted.

Now install windows.

to fix mbr,Again boot with live usb. Install a tool called `boot-repair`. Issue following commands to get it

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Now launch `boot-repair` and then use `Recommended Repair`

Good luck. :)

<sub>[Boot-repair docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for all the help, I figured it out. The most important thing you need is an Ubuntu live CD or USB stick. This can be easily created with the Startup Disk Creator application that is installed by default on Ubuntu. After this, use your Ubuntu live CD/USB to make an NTFS partition with GParted. Than install Windows which will break GRUB. GRUB can be fixed again with the live CD/USB using the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
sudo boot-repair
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple fix

ubuntu wont boot from windows bootloader

Follow this guide to re-install ubuntu bootloader GRUB 2 after installing windows.

(http://kasunweranga.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/reinstall-grub2-after-installing.html)

Virtualbox is good but you dont get much 3d support and it is resorce heavy

This guide should work for you it did for me.

Comment: thanks, but that still leaves the issue with the NTFS partition I cannot make..

Comment: Install ubuntu first leave empty space on your hdd for formatting as ntsc insert your windows disc and use that to format the empty space if you need to shrink your ext4 boot in to ubuntu live cd and re-size partitions but make sure you leave empty space for the ntsc.

Comment: @markkirby Hi! while referring  to external link, it's good to add essential part of it. In future the links might not exist.

Comment: Thats a good point I will take this onboard Web-E

Answer (score 0):

This post describes how to set up your computer in order to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows.

Lokk at this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot

Is so easy, good luck!  Use G and our Ubuntu site for your question..  :)

Comment: He has some specific problem. You should read the question carefully.

Answer (score -1):

What about using virtualbox, it work fine for me. take a look at this site
[VirtualBox for Linux](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).

Comment: no I don't want to use virtualbox because it's too recourse heavy. I probably have to run some heavy graphic programs so I just want a clean dual boot.